# How to make localhost https in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, https, openssl, localhost, package.json

In package.json

```
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=key.pem&&react-scripts start",
```

I have cert.pem and key.pem under my root folder. After doing this the localhost looks like below

[image]

But I am not sure if this is working or not as even if I change the cert and key name in the above command it still works the same. So I am not understanding if its using the certificates or not.

Comment: A super easy way to do this would be to use `ngrok` and let it create a tunnel to your localhost. It might add to load times though

Comment: @LoXatoR is there any other way to do this rather than ngrok. I do not want slow down my load times.